# Can't start tomcat with launchctl on MacOS: cryptic error

Tags: macos, tomcat

I want to start Tomcat on MacOS X Server, so i wrote following `plist` and placed it into `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.apache.tomcat</string>
        <key>ProgamArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/catalina.sh</string>
                <string>run</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The sytax check shows that all is ok. But trying to load it with following command:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist
```

I got following error that i can't undrstand:

```
org.apache.tomcat: Invalid argument
```

Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error in `ProgamArguments` text. It seems that syntax check don't check for correct text inside xml tags, just checks that tags are correct :(.